# Can a pod make itself unavailable temporarily in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Can a Kubernetes pod that is connected to a service make itself look unavailable temporarily to the service so that no traffic is scheduled on that pod? And make itself available again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a `readiness` probe. When a pod is not `ready`, it gets no requests. So you could define a readiness probe, and make it fails. [More](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in these ways:

1.delete the Deployment/Statefulset that is connected to the Service K8s (or the Service itself) <-- easier if you have some chain of DevOps for deploy

2.scaling the replica of your Deployment to 0 <-- `kubectl -n NAMESPACE scale --replicas=0 deployment APP-NAME`

3.patch (via kubectl or editing the YAML file) the Deployment by changing the label associated with the Service, so that it does not match <-- last resort
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates